# update sobject class

Tags: class, update, wsdl

I'm trying to update sobject from one to another sf org.

I import my custom wsdl *sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom* and *sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom*, i pass login but i cannot able to update an sobject.

I did on visual studio by vb without issue but here I don't find the solution.

Developer console says: *Illegal assignment from sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.Account to sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x*

Any suggest please? I think that the issue will be with create/insert too.

```
public class myclass_timer  implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts  {
public void execute ( QueueableContext  context) {  

sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.Account acctest = new sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.account();
acctest.Id = '0015800000E0AAA';
acctest.Description = 'testttt';

list<sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x> listsobj = new list<sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x>();
sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x sobj = new sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x(); 
       
sobj = acctest; //<--- ERRORRRRRR   
    
listsobj.add(sobj);
list<enterpriseSoapSforceCom.SaveResult> listsaveres = new list<enterpriseSoapSforceCom.SaveResult>();
    listsaveres = sfclient.update_x(listsobj);
}
}
```

The class for sobject_x imported by wsdl. Maybe is there an error when converting wsdl to class(i used FuseIT SFDC Explorer):

```
    public class sObject_x {
    public String[] fieldsToNull;
    // Restriction enumeration: 
    public String Id;
    private transient String[] fieldsToNull_type_info = new String[]{'fieldsToNull',s_ns0,'string','0','-1','true'};
    private transient String[] Id_type_info = new String[]{'Id',s_ns0,'ID','1','1','true'};
    private transient String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{s_ns0,'true','false'};
    private transient String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fieldsToNull','Id'};
}
```